# What's wrong with my rails value assignment containing a question mark?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Order` modle and it has `delivered?` boolean type attribute. In rails console, `Order.first.delivered?` returns `false`, so I assume `Order` does have this attribute. However I have an error in my `order controller`, and it says my

```
@order.delivered? = false
```

, reporting

```
syntax error, unexpected '=' @order.delivered? = false ^`.
```

What's wrong with my rails value assignment?

--
Edit:

I defined an attribute `delivered?` in Order model, and in rails console, `Order` returns `delivered?: boolean`, so I think the attribute name includes the `?` question mark.

Edit2:

In the migration file, I defined as:

```
def change
  add_column :orders, :delivered?, :boolean
end
```

Comment: I don't think you can have a question mark in your column name.

Comment: Please show the code for how you defined an attribute called `delivered?` for your model. You can have a question mark in the name of a method, but Ruby doesn't let you create an attribute writer with a question mark in the name. Or are you saying it's actually defined that way in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is caused by your attribute `delivered?` with `?`

in rails console, type `Order.new.methods.select {|e| e =~ /delivered\?/}`, you can see all the methods with `delivered?`

=> [:delivered?, :"delivered?=", :"delivered?_before_type_cast", :"delivered?_came_from_user?", :"delivered??", :"delivered?_changed?", :"delivered?_change", :"delivered?_will_change!", :"delivered?_was", :"reset_delivered?!", :"restore_delivered?!"]

But ruby can not parse `delivered?=` or `delivered??` method properly. So I suggest you to rename your attribute from `delivered?` to `delivered`, and Rails would generate a predicate method named `delivered?`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set the delivered status of @order use:

```
@order.delivered = false
```

If you're checking whether it's false if a conditional clause you can just do:

```
if !@order.delived?
 # handle not delivered
```

or perhaps more idiomatically:

```
unless @order.delivered?
 # handled not delivered
```

The version with a question mark at the end only *reads* the value of the delivered attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`?=` cannot be interpreted by ruby. This involves both the attribute of boolean entity(?) and the assignment(=), thus flummoxing the MRI(I assume you are using Ruby MRI).

It will not be able to parse `?=` since there aren't any such methods available.

The better solution will be naming your attribute without the question mark and at execution time, a method `delivered?` will automatically be created.